# xcode5 simulator app crashes keychain-access-groups not allowed

Tags: macos, ios7, coronasdk, provisioning

my app crashes in the simulator.

Just installed OSX Mavericks with XCode 5.
Developed the app using Corona SDK.

I deleted my old provisioning profiles and created new ones.
my Bundle ID is something like com.company.appname

I get the following error message in the console log from the simulator:

killed testapp[pid xxxx] because its use of the keychain-access-groups entitlement is not allowed (error code -67030)

I already deleted all old project screenshots / files. Don't know what to do.

The compiled app runs fine on my iphone 3gs with iOS 6.1 though.

any help highly appreciated
roman

Answer (score 0):

Corona's engineering team is looking into this.  Please add your information to this post on the Corona SDK Forums

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/40706-app-crashes-in-xcode-simulator-ios-7-sdk/page-2